# For loop on pandas dataframe causing slow performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, running-count

I currently have a loop in a script that is designed to process a raw test data file, and perform a bunch of calculations during the sanitised data. During the script, I need to figure out exactly how many cycles there are in each test. A cycle can be defined by when the `step` value contained a position `i` is greater than the next `step`, `i+1`. For example, the step count would reach, 4, and the next step is 1, so the next step is the beginning of a new cycle. So far I  am calculating this with this simple loop:

```
raw_data = {'Step':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]}


cycle_test = 1


for i in range(len(raw_data)-1):
    if  raw_data['Step'][i] > raw_data['Step'][i+1]:
        raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
        cycle_test+=1
    else:
        raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
```

This works fine, but the `raw_data` being provided is very large, and my script is taking forever on this calculation. I've used `rolling` before to do `max` and `min` comparisons before, but is it possible to use that to replace this for loop?

Comment: please create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because as it is, it's much harder to help you. I guess you need [diff function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), but can't help more without example

Comment: Thanks, I have created a small dataset `raw_data['Step']` to help make the code repoducible

Comment: This code is still not reproducible. Try to paste it into separate script and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'Step':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df['CycleTest'] = (df['Step'].diff() < 0).cumsum() + 1

print(df)
```

```
    Step  CycleTest
0      1          1
1      1          1
2      2          1
3      2          1
4      2          1
5      3          1
6      3          1
7      4          1
8      4          1
9      4          1
10     1          2
11     2          2
12     2          2
13     3          2
14     3          2
15     3          2
16     4          2
17     4          2
18     4          2
19     4          2
20     1          3
21     2          3
22     2          3
23     3          3
24     3          3
25     4          3
26     4          3
27     4          3
```

Check when the value gets smaller with `diff` and use `cumsum` to cumulatively count those occurrences.

Comment: Thank you! I'm seeing a performance difference already. :)